# To late to give two weeks notice

Tags: resignation

I recently had a job offer with a really good airline in the aviation industry. I am going to keep the airlines names out of the equation because that is not very important. What is important is why don't companies honor the two weeks’ notice anymore ? One of the things I said in the interview was I wanted to give a two weeks’ notice to my employer because they were good to me. The HR person in the interview said, " oh yes we will honor that." In all fairness she did say it may be a little tight. Which I thought okay, I can deal with it being a little close as long as I can put in my two weeks’ notice. I received a phone call at the beginning of the month that they would like to move forward and start a background check on me with a conditional job offer upon completion of it. I was really excited beyond belief!! To make a long story short they sent me the job offer about a week and a half before my class date of June 1st. For those of you who do not know the airline industry. Whenever you have a skilled position that is regulated by the FAA. You have to go through a series of classes when you start over at a new airline.To ensure they are covering there company procedures and FAA regulations. It took them almost a week later to get back to me on whether or not there was another class, which there wasn't and I pretty much could take it or leave it. I did try and make it work with the four days I had left but I couldn't make the move in that time under the time constraints involved. The move was over 1200 miles. 
Hindsight is 20/20 but part of me is really kicking myself for not taking the new job. I did call and leave an email explaining my reasons for not being able to make the class date and that I was still interested in a job at their company. Of course I haven't heard back from them. Part of me felt like I was being forced to burn a bridge between the two companies with the time involved. My current company has a do not rehire clause, if you don't give a two weeks’ notice then they will put you on the ineligible for rehire list. The company I applied for is a really good company to work for outside of this incident. My questions are: What is the likelihood of me being able to reapply at this job? What would HR's standpoint be? And has anyone else noticed in large corporate America that giving the two weeks’ notice is becoming something of a bye gone formality?

Comment: Your post can use some  serious editing for clarity.

Comment: I think there are multiple questions that I am asking and I should of asked them at the end which is confusing everyone. I will keep it simple. Basicaly what I am asking is the two week rule something that is not followed as much anymore? Secondly, yes my current employer was good to me and I wanted to give my two weeks notice which I thought they deserved. If I were to apply again does anyone have any experience in dealing with HR  in a situation like this ? Thank you for your answer...

Comment: Still unclear to me. "_they sent me the job offer about a week and a half before **my class date** of June 1st_" What class? The training class the company provided? Or the class in your school? You truly need to clarify the question. What exactly is two weeks notice played in this whole issue?

Comment: The training class for the job that I am taking at the airline I was applying for. With the type of job I have when we start over at another airline we have to go through a certain amount of training put forth by the FAA.I don't want to reveal what kind of job I do and the airlines that are involved. I am interested in any opinions that someone may have on the HR issues that were involved.

Comment: The mistake you made is that you should have said you must give two weeks notice to your current employer **after** you receive the formal concrete written offer (not the one before background check) when your prospective employer gave you verbal conditional offer. As everybody said, **only** written unconditional offer counts. Before that, never quit your current job. Please learn this lesson.

Comment: Your question was out on hold as 'unclear what you are asking'. After your edit I still will not vote to reopen until you read http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: HR knew about giving a two weeks notice in the interview as I said previously in the above description. It is stil common in the aviation industry to be giving a two weeks notice. Although we have noticed a trend with very large companies to be overlooking this practice when hiring new employees. I think this is the wrong forum to be asking questions like this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's not clear to me which of the two companies isn't "honoring" your two-week notice nor how it's not being "honored". That needs clarification for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current employer treats you fairly, then you owe them the two-week notice.

Now, things may happen and you may find yourself in a situation where the two-week notice is too long. In this case, you should go back to your employer and see if shortening your notice will not cause them pain. For example, if you are not doing anything critical for them at the moment,they probably don't need to hold you for the full two weeks. But you have to ask. Next time, ask.

I think your prospective employer was rough on you and it wasn't good of them to put you into such a tight spot. They should have known that, while they would have preferred to have you on board earlier, that's not something that's always possible. You can always reapply but if they refuse, they refuse and they most probably won't walk you through their rationale. And their decision to refuse is nothing that you can affect.

Comment: "I think your prospective employer was rough on you and it wasn't good of them to put you into such a tight spot."  OP may have dodged a bullet there.